# How do I hide my original show button and allow click anywhere to hide my content?

Tags: jquery, click, show-hide

I am trying to figure out how I can hide my original show button. Then make it so when I click anywhere on the page its hides the content that was originalyl shown by show button.

```
<script>
    $(function(){

        $(".content").hide();
        $('.more-btn').click(function(){
           $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.content').show();
           $(this).hide();
        });

    });
</script>
```

here is the HTML

```
<section>
    <article class="toggle-box" id="toggle1">
        <aside class="info-rollover">
            <h3>Locavores</h3>
            <button class="more-btn">Show More</button>
        </aside>
    </article>
    <aside class="content">
        <img src="images/loca/1.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/loca/2.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/loca/3.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/loca/4.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/loca/5.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/loca/6.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/loca/7.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/loca/8.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/loca/9.jpg"/>
    </aside>
</section>
```

The new hide show on click code

```
                   $(document).click(function(){
                    $('.content:visible').hide();
                    $('.content>img:hidden').show(),$('body').css('cursor', 'default');
                    });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to a body click once you've hidden your button.

```
$( '.more-btn').click( function(){
  var button=$( this ).hide(),
  content= $('.content' ).show();
  $( 'body' ).bind( 'click.more', function( e ){
    $( this ).unbind( 'click.more' );
    button.show();
    content.hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: the button has been removed from the code.  That why I added to the post thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ozejib/2/edit)**

```
$(function(){

    $(".content").hide();
    $('.more-btn').click(function( e ){
       e.stopPropagation(); // to lower "DOM layers"
       $(this).closest('section').find('.content').show();
       $(this).hide();
    });

    $(document).click(function(){
      $('.content:visible').hide();
      $('.more-btn:hidden').show();
    });

});
```

Comment: That works great,  just a quick question regarding why the e is necessary? And this would work without stopping the propagation?

Comment: Glad that worked! thanks. About the `e`vent: take the time to try it yourself: http://jsbin.com/ozejib/3/edit

Comment: Hey @Roxon you're awesome, thanks for your help,  Im adding on to this. I actually decided I didn't want a a button to open and close my div. I tried to figure this out and got stuck here. Because if I click on any of the content areas it doesn't do any thing I have to click the outside.  This makes it impossible to close on a the mobile side of things.

     $(document).click(function(){
               $('.content:visible').hide();
               $('.content>img:hidden').show(),$('body').css('cursor', 'default');
               });
             
          });

Comment: Please setup a demo where you stuck and describe your issue.

Comment: @ZakFerris I cannot let you edit my post Zak, go here http://jsbin.com/ and setup a demo.

Comment: How can I help with this link? @Zak... please edit here: http://jsbin.com/ozejib/2/edit

Comment: i need to be able to click anywhere and close the div